# Query state instance of glassfish 3.1.2.2 server

Tags: glassfish-3, high-availability, haproxy

Can i somehow get via http the state of one instance of a glassfish cluster. I want to use the state for a connection to haproxy load balancer.

Answer (score -1):

Check out Glassfish Group Management Service: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18930_01/html/821-2426/gjfnl.html

Comment: Don't just post a link only answer.  At least summarize what can be found at the link